# Update Action with no show view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an Item model that I do not need a separate show view for. Instead, when the item is updated I would like to return the user to the index. When the form is submitted to edit an item, you get an error like this : `No route matches [PUT] "/items/1"`

Here is the routes file

```
Order::Application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  resources :static_pages
  resources :customers
  resources :demands

  resources :items, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :index, :edit]


end
```

Here is the controller

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @items = Item.all
    end

    def new
        @item = Item.new
    end

    def create
        @item = Item.new(params[:item])
        if @item.save
            flash[:success] = "Item saved!"
            redirect_to items_path
        else
            render new_item_path
        end
    end

    def destroy
        Item.find(params[:id]).destroy
        redirect_to items_path
    end

    def edit
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
        if @item.update_attributes(params[:item])
            redirect_to 'items#index'
            flash[:success] = "Item updated!"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end 


end
```

Here is the model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :price

  validates :name, presence: true

  VALID_PRICE_REGEX = /^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*\.[0-9]{2}$/
  validates :price, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_PRICE_REGEX}

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `update` action for `items` in your routes file.

```
resources :items, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :index, :edit]
```

should be

```
resources :items, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :index, :edit, :update]
```

or, more concisely,

```
resources :items, except: [:show]
```

Comment: ahh of course. I can't believe I missed something so simple. Thank you!